# If I enable 32bit applications for a site in IIS 8 i get 500 - Internal server error

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5, iis-8

If I enable 32bit applications for a site in IIS 8. i get the following error:

500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

pl help.

Comment: Are you using ABCPdf in your project?

Comment: no ABCPdf is not being used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resolution found to this is to remove the following modules from the iis manager:

1) DynamicCompressionModule
2) StaticCompressionModule

---

To do it follow the below steps in iis manager:

step 1: iis home - modules - unlock these two modules
step 2: sites - website home - modules - remove these two modules

---

Now in application pools – select the application pool – Advanced Settings – Change the ‘Enable 32-Bit Applications’ to true

---

This would avoid the internal server error: “500 - Internal server error. There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.”

To narrow down on the error for finding the specific error; the following should be carried out before the above steps:

In iis manager – Sites – website home – Error pages – Open Feature – select the status code 500 – Edit Feature Settings… - Select Detailed errors and click OK

This would give the detailed error message as below (using it the exact modules that causes the error can be found; earlier we only got the error message: “500 - Internal server error. There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.”):

HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
Most likely causes:
•   The worker process is unable to read the applicationhost.config or web.config file. 
•   There is malformed XML in the applicationhost.config or web.config file. 
•   The server cannot access the applicationhost.config or web.config file because of incorrect NTFS permissions. 
Things you can try:
•   Look in the event logs for information about why the configuration files are not readable. 
•   Make sure the user identity specified for the application pool, or the authenticated user, has the required permissions to access the web.config file. 
Detailed Error Information:
Module     DynamicCompressionModule
Notification       SendResponse
Handler    Not yet determined
Error Code     0x804500c1
Requested URL      http://webaddress.com/

Physical Path      X:/Path
Logon Method       Not yet determined
Logon User     Not yet determined

More Information:
This error occurs when there is a problem reading the configuration file for the Web server or Web application. In some cases, the event logs may contain more information about what caused this error. 
View more information »

Comment: what side-effects will occur by removing these two modules.. that requires an answer..